# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable on Python Twitter API

Tags: python, for-loop, twitter, iterable

I am extracting text, screen_name, hashtags, follower counts, etc from tweets using Twitter library.

I have no problems getting screen_name, hashtags, and text because they are all strings.

How can I extract follower counts which is 'int' object and save into the format of list?

```
status_texts = [status['text']
                for status in statuses]
```

```
screen_names = [user_mention['screen_name']
                for status in statuses
                    for user_mention in status['entities']['user_mentions']]
```

```
followers = [user['followers_count']
            for status in statuses
                for user in status['user']['followers_count']]
```

Result of first two codes are

```
["RT @ESPNStatsInfo: Seven of the NBA's top 10 all-time leading scorers never had back-to-back 50-point games. \n\nKareem Abdul-Jabbar\nKarl Mal…", 'RT @kirkgoldsberry: The game has changed. Rookie LeBron versus Doncic"]
```

```
['ESPNStatsInfo', 'kirkgoldsberry', 'ESPNStatsInfo', 'warriors', 'MT_Prxphet', 'Verzilix', 'BleacherReport']
```

My expected result is

`[10930,13213,15322,8795,9328,23519]`

But when I try to extract the number of followers and save them into the format of list, it returns `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I know I am getting this error because result of follower_counts is in integer and I can't use `for` with integer.

In this case, do I need to convert `int` into `str` ? or do I need to use `range` ?

I know using `tweepy` is much easier way but I want to use `twitter` first

Comment: The error is pretty much self-explanatory, `status['user']['followers_count']` returns an integer and you try to iterate in it. Also, you can't convert this into an user. You'll have to find an other way

Comment: So give us what result you expect. Maybe the solution is iterating on user to get their followers_count. But we can't know until you tell us exactly what you want

Comment: @Nenri Thank you for the comment. First, I know `status['user']['followers_count']` returns an integer but I do not know how I could extract `followers_count` from tweets without using `for` iteration. Second, I don't understand what you meant by "you can't convert this into an user". Tweets were in the format of JSON and `followers_count` was under `users` ?

Comment: You should rewrite your entire question with what you actually want.

Comment: @Nenri Ok I will do it now

Comment: I am answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I expect the dictionnary representating the json response from your API call to be called `jsonResponse`.

This way, you already know that you can get every tweet by doing `statuses = jsonResponse['statuses']`. (I'm expecting your `statuses` to be that too.)

From there,i'm guessing that you want a list of amount of followers for each tweets. So for status in statuses, you want the followers count. Which , in python, looks simply like this :

```py
followers_counts = [status['user']['followers_count'] for status in statuses]
```

An other way is to map the `statuses` list :

```py
followers_count = map(lambda status: status['user']['followers_count'], statuses)
```

With `map` you can even more simply make a dictionnary of the infos you want for each tweet. But that would just look like the json you already get from the API.

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the bad question written in bad English grammar. 
From your answer is `statuses = jsonResponse['statuses']` same as this?
`search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)`
`statuses = search_results['statuses']`

Comment: Yes it is. as i didn't know if you were using a module or a direct API call, i couldn't know what `jsonResponse` is got from. But it is same as `search_results` in your case.

Comment: When making a list of amount of followers for each tweets, your code used `for` iteration only once. But when I tried to extract screen_name like I wrote on my question, I used `for` iteration twice. Is this simply because I can't use `for` iteration for `int`? or format of JSON ?

Comment: @김도훈 No, it's because user_mentions is a list, so you retrieve all user mentions from all tweets. I advice you to do : `screen_names = [[user_mention['screen_name'] for user_mention in status['entities']['user_mentions']] for status in statuses]`

This will give you a list of all user_mentions for each tweet while `user_mentions` is a list of all screen names of user mentions. `followers_counts` is a single value for each status, so we just need one for loop.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for bothering you but I have one last question about the answer code. Based on your code, I was able to get a list of follower counts. To compute the maximum number of follower_counts, I did `print(max(followers_counts))` which returned `20323629`. Then I tried to know where that number locates in the list by `followers_counts.index(20323629)` which returned 926. Then I did `screen_names[926]` which returned 'DevinBook` I went on twitter to check but he had only 641,885 followers. I tried `[925],[927]` but still didn't match. What went wrong here?

Comment: That's exactly what i told in the previous message. Your current screen_names append all mentions, so if a message has several mentions in it, it appends them all. And can take several indexes. So the user which has 20323629 followers can be anywhere after index 926. To prevent this problem, apply what i told you in the previous message